# Unable to make payment with credit card on paypal's sandbox env. with android sdk

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox, paypal

Unable to make payment with credit card on paypal's sandbox env. with android sdk. I am getting following error:

E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:500,exception:Internal Server Error

E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"82672dcf5826b"}

Please guide to rectify this.Thanks.